# Bootstrap responsive height issue

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, image-size

Im having a hard time to understand what is going on with some images when using bootstrap 3 so hoping someone can explain.

I have the following markup to style some images

```
                <div class="row footer-media">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h5>Recent Videos</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="title">
                    <h5>@hallOfFame.GetPropertyValue("pageHeading")</h5>
                </div>
                @if (hallOfFame.HasValue("hallOfFameGallery"))
                {
                    foreach (var image in hofMediaFolder.Children)
                    {
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 hof-images">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="@image.Url" alt="@image.Name" title="@image.Name" />
                        </div>

                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

The outcome is as follows

[image]

Why does the first image on the second row have a higher height than all the other images? The image is the exact same size as the others (640x480)

[image]

How can i ensure that all images (regardless of thier dimensions) are scaled to the same size, line up correctly and resize appropriately when the breakpoint changes? Does bootstrap offer a special class to achieve this or is there anything out there that i can use?

Thanks

Edit*
I have now created a fiddle to show my issue, it can be viewed here https://jsfiddle.net/muncher39/um04cwmp/1/. The images being used in the fiddle are the exact same images that i am using on my site. It turns out that the image dimensions are not all the same but im still unsure why this should be an issue?

Image sizes are as follows

```
1.image5.jpg = 640x480
2.image7.jpg = 640x480
3.image1.jpg = 640x480
4.image2.jpg = 640x480
5.image4.jpg = 3888x2592
6.image6.jpg = 1944x1296
7.image3.jpg = 1944x1296
```

Comment: Have u missed < in div or is that a typo?

Comment: Yes sorry that is a typo, i will correct this now. Thanks

Comment: Have you given fixed height to div? Before that is image size matching other images?

Comment: I have given no fixed height on the div as the image sizes are all 640x480 I thought this would work? or am i missing something?

Comment: Can u share jsfiddle please?

Comment: And where are yor '<div class="row"><!--Your col divs--></div>'

Comment: @Korgrue That's a good answer - you should post it below instead of a comment.

Comment: Fernando, he has his columns defined. See the screenshot he included. You can wrap as many columns in a single row as you want with bootstrap. Once the columns add up to more than 12 in that row, it will automatically break the next columns to the next row for you.

Comment: Updated the code snippet to demonstrate all my markup

Comment: Is there some CSS for the `hof-images` class?

Comment: You should have another `row` tag around your inner columns, but that's not causing the height issue. If the images are the exactly same HxW it should work fine: http://www.codeply.com/go/cvNBOsu9Ou __ is there any other CSS?

Comment: Yes the images are definately the same H&W! so frustrating. However, this must be an image issue becuase if i replace the source for //placehold.it/640x480 they stack as expected?

Comment: Only padding-right:0 on the hof-images

Answer (score 3):

Put them in a wrapper div (one wrapper div per image), and set them to background cover for the individual image divs - aligned center, center. Set overflow to hidden on the image container divs. Set the size of the image containers to width:100% and height to a fixed amount. The images will be clipped at the edges if they are the incorrect aspect ratio - but they will always take up consistent height. The width will be controlled by the column width and they wont get skewed when resizing the window.

Since you want it to be dynamic - you will just need to set the image paths (and some of the css) via JS/jQuery as demonstrated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 hof-images">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 hof-images">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 hof-images">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 hof-images">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 hof-images">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 hof-images">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    height:250px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.image').eq(0).css("background", "url(http://placehold.it/450x350)").css("backgroundRepeat", "no-repeat").css("backgroundPosition", "center center");
$('.image').eq(1).css("background", "url(http://placehold.it/550x350)").css("backgroundRepeat", "no-repeat").css("backgroundPosition", "center center");
$('.image').eq(2).css("background", "url(http://placehold.it/450x450)").css("backgroundRepeat", "no-repeat").css("backgroundPosition", "center center");
$('.image').eq(3).css("background", "url(http://placehold.it/450x350)").css("backgroundRepeat", "no-repeat").css("backgroundPosition", "center center");
$('.image').eq(4).css("background", "url(http://placehold.it/650x350)").css("backgroundRepeat", "no-repeat").css("backgroundPosition", "center center");
$('.image').eq(5).css("background", "url(http://placehold.it/450x450)").css("backgroundRepeat", "no-repeat").css("backgroundPosition", "center center");
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/vz9c03yt/2/)

Comment: Can you please provide an example of this? Ideally i would like the user to upload any image of any size and be able to handle them responsively

Comment: Yes, standby for a moment while I work up a Fiddle for you.

Comment: Yes, that is the way to go! It is the technique I use when I want to have suitable responsive images in Bootstrap. There's no built-in classes in Bootstrap for that, but you don't need them as it is simple to solve with CSS.

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed` is for parallax effect, why is it included in `.image` class? Also, it is interesting to avoid JS if not necessary. I would include `background: none center center no-repeat;` in `.image` class, and then `style="background-image:url(/path/to/specific/image)"` in every desired div to set the actual images, since it will be easier for the OP to use in his current piece of code. Edited example: https://jsfiddle.net/vz9c03yt/3/

Comment: background-attachment: fixed is for parallax effect, why is it included in....:

Because I took it from old code of mine and forgot to strip it out when I pasted it in. It wont hurt anything in this implementation - but can definitely be removed without any impact.

>Also, it is interesting to avoid JS if not necessary:

I agree, but can't unfortunately - OP noted that his images must be dynamic and in order for this method to work - JS is going to be needed.

The rest of your suggestions are all perfectly fine additions. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks i will certainly have a go at implementing this :). Can you check my fiddle to see what the prob is with my original issue? its really bugging me.

Comment: Looks like it is as simple as you are pulling in images of different aspect ratios - this will result in things not aligning. You did not doing aythng wrong per se - you just not going to get to the goal you want if you don't have any way to control size and manage aspect ratio. The solution I provided will do both. Really, you can extend it to your "for each" loop - so long as you update the CSS and HTML to do what I did - and in the loops you add the images as css background images instead of inline HTML images.